# JSON Parsing URI+textbox

Tags: json

```
http://example.com/doctracklog/20140827091936
```

I need to parse JSON from a URI ff, such as the sample above.

Built-in URI(http://example.com/doctracklog/)+(textbox1) followed by `textbox1`;
only the values of `textbox1` will change.

It can be in Android, JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, but I will post a generic solution with **PHP** / **JQUERY** / **JS** / **AJAX** / **.HTACCESS**

### File Structure

[image]

---

### Create `.htaccess` file in document root /

This rewrite rules will make the friendly URL `/doctracklog/{some-value}` works.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule doctracklog/(.*)/? doctracklog.php?id=$1
```

---

### Create `doctracklog.php` file in document root / (JS - JQUERY - AJAX)

This code will read the json object and display user information of the specific error

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <!-- javascript/jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <div id="holder"></div>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '/json.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'id': '<?php echo !empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";?>'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 'Error') {
                console.log(response);
                alert(response.user.name + "-" + response.user.age + "-" + response.user.gender);
            } else {
                alert(response.message);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Create `json.php` file in document root / (PHP)

This file will set which user will be displayed based on the passed value (http://example.com/doctracklog/**20140827091936**) and we returns a json object

```
<?php
//this is the number you are passing in your URI. For ex. http://example.com/doctracklog/20140827091936
$userId = $_POST['id'] ? $_POST['id'] : "";

//This is a dummy array example, so we can use userId as its index
if(!empty($userId)) {
    $users = array(
        '20140827091936' => array(
            'name' => 'John',
            'age' => '20',
            'gender' => 'male'
        ),
        '20140920081120' => array(
            'name' => 'Susan',
            'age' => '32',
            'gender' => 'female'
        )
    );

    if(array_key_exists($userId,$users)) {
        $json = array('status' => 'OK', 'user' => $users[$userId]);
    } else {
        $json = array('status' => 'Error','message' => 'Id does not exist');
    }
} else {
    $json = array('status' => 'Error','message' => 'You did not pass any id');
}

//return json object
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

---

### Test Cases:

These are some of the possible examples.

**No Id**: http://example.com/doctracklog/

**Wrong Id**: http://example.com/doctracklog/111111111

**Right Id**: http://example.com/doctracklog/20140827091936

---

### Results

These are the results of the examples.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLnZ8.jpg please see the attached image, And many thanks Lea Tano for the input, i hope you see this post and give me some feedback thank you.

Comment: @aqie sure, please attach the file in question and explain with your words what this form should do.

Comment: looking at the attached image,  i want to make an android app that will aggregate the information given the sample json file and i want to get the latest info. log with the most recent date. the textbox doctrack #. where the user will input their 14digit control no. i hope you understand my problem.